# django charfield not showing in admin panel

Tags: python, django

i create a model in django and register it in admin.py when i go to admin panel it shows the model but when i want to create object it doesn't show the charfields and i can just create the oject without any details

this is my codes below

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Feature

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    features = Feature.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'features' : features})
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Feature(models.Model):
    name: models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details: models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

stting.py

```
"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.12.

For more information on this file, see

For the full list of settings and their values, see
 """

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-dubzu2qq@tk9lk%d05a*@j1rd1hkr$v72eiga+*u7%v2d)19_5'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'livesync',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'livesync.core.middleware.DjangoLiveSyncMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

# Default primary key field type

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Feature


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Feature)
```

this screenshot is from my admin panel > add Feature (myModel) and it shows nothing.

[screenshot of admin panel> add Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDUNj.png)

Comment: restart your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `@dataclass` way of defining your model. I'm not aware that will work ... It should be:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Also, have you run migrations? (I suspect not or I think you'd have seen an error here). You should run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate` when you create or amend a model definition - this is what creates/changes it in the DB, and without that there's not a lot to display in admin anyway ...

It's possible if you ran migrate it created an "empty" model maybe, since you were missing the `=` - I really don't know exactly what this code would do without testing it.

Comment: oh!!!‍♂️ i'm new to python and i'm learning it.. thank you very much it was the " = " sign that i forgot.. it's working now! thanks again.